# Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined at angular-moment.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, momentjs

I've been sitting with this problem about an hour, I'm not sure what went wrong. I've been looking this question at stackoverflow, but nothing can help me. I tried to putting Moment js in my project.

1. Refer to this link (https://github.com/urish/angular-moment)
2. Already follow the instruction.
3. Got error: angular is not defined at angular-moment.js:630.

This is my code:

**index.html**

```
<!-- moment extension -->
    <script src="lib/moment/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-moment/angular-moment.js"></script>

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&amp;sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic-timepicker/dist/ionic-timepicker.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
```

**Javascript**

```
angular.module('starter.controller', ['ionic', 'ionic-timepicker', 'angularMoment'])
.controller('checkoutOrderCtrl', function ($scope, moment) {
        var NowMoment = moment();
        $rootScope.date = NowMoment.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        $rootScope.time = NowMoment.format('h:mm:ss');
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: I hope this is not a stupid question. But you din´t load angular.js anywhere, did you?

Comment: You should put your `angular.moment.js` after `angular.js` script tag.

Comment: Where is the Angular JS file? Then you need to put angular-moment after that.

Comment: Oh I see, actually I already add "angular.js" after "angular.moment.js" before this. But got same error, so now everything already fixed by putting "angular.js" before "angular.moment.js" and after that it give me warning "WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to place `angular-moment.js` after `angular.js` file:

```
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- moment extension -->
<script src="lib/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-moment/angular-moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh I see, actually I already add "angular.js" after "angular.moment.js" before this. But got same error, so now everything already fixed by putting "angular.js" before "angular.moment.js" and after that it give me warning "WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once."

Comment: You are loading it twice. Check the JS script files you are loading into the page.